# How to access google fit user's email in Android

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am building a step tracker on Android and had a successful integration with Google Fit. However, I can't access user's gmail address. Could anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve Users email address you have to implement Google Plus API, to use plus API make sure you add play services dependencies in your `build.grade`.

```
compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1
```

After that use this code snippet to retrieve user email address.

```
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
  Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
  String userEmail=currentPerson.getEmail();
}
```